# I am trying to split the text into paragraphs, it is splitting on commas instead of new line or paragraph using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I am new to Javascript.  I am trying to split the text into paragraphs using split method using Javascript. The data is splitting on commas instead of new line or paragraph as shown below.

I am giving below input in DB: `Math & English &Science`

Output coming: `Math,English,Science`

```
var subjects;
var subject;
for (var i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < responseText.length; j++) {

    subjects = responseText[j].name;

    subject = subjects.split("&");
    console.log(subject);
    var Obj = {
      projectName: responseText[j].name,
      projectDescription: subject,
      currentStatus: responseText[j].rollno
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
Math
English
Science
```

Could you please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: I don't see any commas anywhere in your text. And there's no newlines in the original text.

Comment: Are you asking about splitting or joining?

Comment: `split` = turn string into array. `join` = turn array back into string.

Comment: You can also use `console.log(subject.join('\n'))` to put newlines between them.

Comment: @Barmar, I am asking about splitting . I want when there is '&' symbol in DB, new line should start . As i have lot of data in DB. So, i want to split into paragraphs or new line when '&' is found in DB

Comment: @Barmar, I want to display in JSP page as well. As you can see  var Obj = {
      projectName: responseText[j].name,
      projectDescription: subject,
      currentStatus: responseText[j].rollno
    }  I am passing subject value to projectDescription column. So, i want to display in jsp page as well

Comment: The code we need to see is the code that displays `projectDescription` on the page. It needs to put `<p>` between each element of the array to put them in separate paragraphs.

Comment: @Barmar, now output is coming without commas, but not coming in new line

Comment: but still it is coming in one line. As it is dynamic data...so, data can be anything..this is just small example.So, could you please suggest me to display data in new line

Comment: `split()` turns it into an array. `obj.projectDescription.join('<p>')` will convert it to an HTML string with paragraph breaks between each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do:

```
subject = subjects.replace(/&/g, '<br>');
```

not `split`

Comment: it is splitting the data in new line, If i want to split data based on pipe symbol '|'.  is it different syntax?

Comment: Thank you Kosh. It is working fine. can you please suggest me  If i want to split data based on pipe symbol '|'. is it different syntax?

Comment: It is not splitting, it's replacing '&' with '<br>'. You can find more info here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: yeah..then  If i want to split data based on pipe symbol '|'. is it different syntax?

Comment: Same syntax, my friend (but you'll need to escape the pipe: `/\|/`). Please spend some time for reading the suggested article. It will help you in the future.

Comment: ok sure. Thank you so much for your guidance and your help.:)

Answer (score 1):

When you're displaying the data, put `<br>` between each element of the array.

```js
subjects = "Math & English &Science";

subject = subjects.split("&");
console.log(subject);
var Obj = {
  projectName: "Name",
  projectDescription: subject,
  currentStatus: "Complete"
}

document.getElementById("project").innerHTML = Obj.projectDescription.join("<br>");
```

```html
Project description:
<div id="project">
</div>
```

Comment: It looks fine Barmar. I am trying it

Comment: It is working fine, Thank you Barmar, Can i use '|' instead of '&' ?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. There's nothing special about `&`.